# Reset the layout parameters of a programmatically modified widget (e.g. textview) from the xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a simple enough question:

If I modify a widget (e.g.) textview by changing something programmitically (e.g. the text and background colour), how do I reset it to what was specified in the original xml layout file, **[edit]** without writing out the code to do it all manually **[/edit]**? Can I grab all the parameters for the textview specified in the layout and then apply them somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Reset programmatically to the default parameters as in the layout.

Comment: You mean by just writing out the code to do that? But I want to avoid that because I have many views I want to reset, and the class I am writing should not need know the specific details of what the views looked like before I changed them. Sorry I should have said I want to grab the info from the xml file.

Comment: okay, then define a `style` for the corresponding widget in your `style.xml` file and try setting it programmatically, in that way you won't need to specify the parameters in your class except the `style`.

Comment: hmm, its not ideal as there's no way to access the styles easily. I think I'll have to design my program to not have to make reversions like that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found to this problem was:

- before changing the layout, save it on a field on your class;

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsTvOriginal;

...
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        this.layoutParamsTvOriginal = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) displayTextView.getLayoutParams();
...
```

- Create a new `LayoutParams` to change its values

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsTvNew = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParamsTvOriginal); //create new to change values
layoutParamsTvNew.verticalBias =  (float) 0.378; //for example
displayTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsTvNew);
```

- when you need to restore the original values:

```
displayTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsTvOriginal);
```